# JavaFX remove default CSS shadow on buttons

Tags: javafx

[image]

**Here is the CSS:**

```
.root{
-fx-background-color: #467b93;
-fx-font-family: 'Tw Cen MT';
-fx-focus-color: transparent;
-fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
}

.button{
-fx-background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
-fx-border-color: red;
-fx-border-width: 0 0 2 0;
-fx-text-fill: white;
-fx-font-size: 18px;
-fx-pref-width: 175px;
-fx-pref-height: 40px;
-fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

As you can see in the picture there is a slight space between the border and the actual border of the button. I can't seem to figure out what's causing this. I have tried setting the `-fx-background-radius` to 0px as well but doesn't seem to work. Also when the button is focused the space in between is removed.

Comment: @James_D nope. Strangely enough this only happens with the bottom border. BTW, the order borders are fine even without `-fx-border-insets`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is a shadow, which is created in the default CSS via a background color with a negative bottom inset. The CSS code in [modena.css](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) which creates this is

```
.button {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-shadow-highlight-color, -fx-outer-border, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1, 2;
}
```

So you could fix this by removing the insets:

```
.button{
-fx-background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
-fx-background-insets: 0 ;
-fx-border-color: red;
-fx-border-width: 0 0 2 0;
-fx-text-fill: white;
-fx-font-size: 18px;
-fx-pref-width: 175px;
-fx-pref-height: 40px;
-fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

Note that the preferred way of creating a border is to use "nested backgrounds". Here you would create a red background with no insets, and then place your "real" background on top of it, with a bottom insets of 2. Since you have transparency in your background, you'll need an intermediate background so the red doesn't show through:

```
.root{

    -fx-background: #467b93;
    -fx-font-family: 'Tw Cen MT';
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;

}

.button{

    -fx-background-color: red, -fx-background, rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 2 0, 0 0 2 0 ;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-font-size: 18px;
    -fx-pref-width: 175px;
    -fx-pref-height: 40px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;

}
```